# Oracle - missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-table

So I am using oracle to create a table Staff of type StaffType however, when I execute the following code:

```
 CREATE TABLE Staff OF StaffType (
    PRIMARY KEY staffNo)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY
    NESTED TABLE nextOfKin STORE AS NextOfKinStorageTable (
    (PRIMARY KEY(Nested_Table_Id, lName, telNo))
    ORGANIZATION INDEX COMPRESS)
    RETURN AS LOCATOR;
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
```

I am not able to understand what is causing this error. I am still sort of new to oracle database so if I haven't provided enough details please let me know what more should I show for my work to make sense? Thanks!

Comment: You have 3 left parens and 4 right ones. Those numbers don't match. The placement of the parentheses you've used doens't seem to make sense, so I can't tell you where the missing one should go.

Comment: What is type "stafftype"? Did you define it somewhere? In any case - what do you think "table staff of stafftype" could mean? That doesn't look like valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: If you want to define an ORDBMS table as an object type, first CREATE TYPE for the single instance (i.e. record) then CREATE TABLE ... OF that type. Although if you're *"sort of new to oracle database"* its ORDBMS stuff is not the place to start (unless you have no choice, in which case good luck!)